# How to properly connect containers created with multiple docker-compose files with isolated networks

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am trying to set up an extensible docker production environment for a few projects on a virtual machine.

My setup is as follows:

Front end: (this works as expected: thanks to [Tevin Jeffery for this](https://tevinjeffrey.me/how-to-setup-nginx-proxy-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker/))

```
# ~/proxy/docker-compose.yml
version: '2'  
services:  
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - '/etc/nginx/vhost.d'
      - '/usr/share/nginx/html'
      - '/etc/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro' 
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro'
    networks:
      - nginx
  letsencrypt-nginx-proxy:
    container_name: letsencrypt-nginx-proxy
    image: 'jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion'
    volumes:
      - '/etc/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    networks:
      - nginx
networks:  
  nginx:
    driver: bridge
```

Database: (planning to add postgres to support rails apps as well)

```
# ~/mysql/docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
#   ports:
#     - 3036:3036
    networks:
      - db
networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge
```

And finaly a wordpress blog to test if everything works:

```
# ~/wp/docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    # external_links:
    #   - mysql_db_1:mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      - proxy_nginx
      - mysql_db
    environment:
      # for nginx and dockergen
      VIRTUAL_HOST: gizmotronic.ca
      # wordpress setup
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql_db_1 
#     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql_db_1:3036  
#     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql 
#     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3036  
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
networks:
  proxy_nginx:
    external: true
  mysql_db:
    external: true
```

My problem is that the Wordpress container can not connect to the database.  I get the following error when I try to start (`docker-compose up`) the Wordpress container:

```
wordpress_1  | Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in - on line 22
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
wp_wordpress_1 exited with code 1
```

## UPDATE:

I was finally able to get this working.  my main problem was relying on the container defaults for the environment variables.  This created an automatic data volume with without a database or user for word press.  After I added explicit environment variables to the mysql and Wordpress containers, I removed the data volume and restarted both containers.  This forced the mysql container to recreate the database and user.

To `~/mysql/docker-compose.yml`:

```
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
  MYSQL_USER: wordpress
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
  MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
```

and to `~/wp/docker-compose.yml`:

```
environment:
  # for nginx and dockergen
  VIRTUAL_HOST: gizmotronic.ca
  # wordpress setup
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql_db_1
  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
```

Comment: The hostname should be the service name, e.g. "db" rather than "mysql_db_1". Can you check if the db is up and running and listening on the port? `docker run -it --rm --net container:mysql_db_1 nicolaka/netshoot netstat -lnt`

Comment: The container name created by docker-compose is mangled: <project name>_<service name>_<container count>.  The netstat command shows the container listening on 44225 and 3036.  The container logs also show mariadb listening for connections.

Comment: Using the unique name that compose gives you prevents you from using the service if it's later scaled or you rename the project later. The alias can be seen with `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{index .Aliases 0}}{{end}}' $container_name`

Comment: I don't expect to have to scale my database for quite some time if ever.  I just don't see why I can't see the db from the wp container.  when I inspect the network, both are on it.  The nginx proxy works.  I am currently checking into the db's bind-address configuration.  This might be blocking connections.

Comment: Why not have all the services in the same compose file? Then you won't have to worry about different docker networks.   You can get around startup issues (make sure wordpress waits for mysql to start 1st) by using the "wait-for-it.sh" https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

If this isn't satisfactory you will need a way to resolve host names between the two networks (aka a DNS gateway server) and pass in the actual hostname/ips in via env variables.

Comment: Or just expose your DB ports on the host machine (#   ports:
#     - 3036:3036 is commented out) and give WP the hostmachine's name as the DB name

Comment: @oneklc The whole idea behind this setup is to be able to add new apps or sites and reuse the proxy and databases.  Check out this site to see how it works:  http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/

Comment: The next step is to create a container like `dockergen` that creates db users and databases from environment variables if they don't exist.

Comment: @cstrutton fair enuf, then just expose the port for the DB to the host machine and use that machines IP/Hostname in your wordpress configuration (then it doesn't even need to be on the same machine). That or when you start up wp link it to the db's network using external link: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#external_links

Answer (score 0):

One problem with docker-compose is that although sometimes your application is linked to your database, the application will NOT wait for your database to be up and ready. Here is an official Docker read:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

I've faced a similar problem where my test application would fail because it couldn't connect to my server because it wasn't up and running yet.

I made a similar workaround to the article posted in the link above by running a shell script to ping the address of the DB until it is available to be used. This script should be the last CMD command in your application.

```
RESPONSE=$(curl --write-out "%{http_code}\n" --silent --output /dev/null "YOUR_MYSQL_DATABASE:3306")

# Until the mysql sends a 200 HTTP response, we're going to keep checking
until [ $RESPONSE -eq "200" ]; do
  sleep 2
  echo "MySQL is not ready yet.. retrying... RESPONSE: ${RESPONSE}"
  RESPONSE=$(curl --write-out "%{http_code}\n" --silent --output /dev/null "YOUR_MYSQL_DATABASE:3306")
done

# Once we know the server's up, we can start run our application 
enter code to start your application here
```

I'm not 100% sure if this is the problem you're having. Another way to debug your problem is to run docker-compose in detached mode with the `-d` flag and run `docker ps` to see if your database is even running. If it is running, run `docker logs $YOUR_DB_CONTAINER_ID` to see if MySQL is giving you any errors when starting

Comment: Database startup is not the issue here.  I start the proxy and the db service first then add other apps to them when I am ready.